# Django to create and change mysql database for learning purposes

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am leaning Python programming language. I have no problems with Python. I read Python official docs, and I can write small programs in Python. I want to familiarize myself with mysql database because it is useful in learning  software development concepts. I've installed mysql database and Django on my computer. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and python 3.4 installed. I've configured Django settings to use mysql database. I tested Django connection to mysql db and all things work properly.

I am a complete newbie with web development. I didn't create my own website and I didn't start developing any web application.

My purpose currently is to master creation of mysql database and tables, making changes/migrations/queries, **using Django models and Python**.

Is it reasonable/possible to use Django ORM for work with mysql database without simultaneous development of a web application/local application? As I've said, I don't have my own website. I want just to try using mysql and Django together on my computer in order to get deeper knowledge as to Django and mysql in this respect.

My final purpose is development in Python, including work with mysql database.

Mysql without Python and Django is of no use for me.

Comment: Use sqlite. Will be better for learning purposes, mainly if you intend learning better about django. When I am creating somtething new, I just started with sqlite because I don´t nedd to worry about databases configs, instaliing, etc. Sqlite commands is simple to use e understand.

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'yourdatabasename.db'),
    }
}

Comment: "Use sqlite. Will be better for learning purposes" is just the worst possible advice for someone wanting to learn and use a rdbms.

Comment: "Mysql without Python and Django is of no use for me" => you can't expect to properly use Django models (the ORM part) if you don't understand how it translates at the database level (schema, queries etc) nor have any notion of proper relational database schemas design. But if you really insist on wasting your time then please go ahead...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn and use MySQL, then start without anything above it - no Django, no ORM, not even a Python script. Learn to configure your mysql server (the server process I mean - doesn't have to be on a distinct computer), to work with the command-line mysql client (database creation, tables creations / modifications, adding/updating/deleting rows, and, most important, doing simple and complex queries).

While you're at it, learn about proper relational data modeling (normalisations etc) so you fully understand how to design your schemas.

Once you're confortable with this, spend some time (should be quite fast at this point) learning to do the same things from python scripts with your python's version mysql connector.

Then if you want to learn web development and Django, well go for it. The ORM is quite easy to use when you already have a good understanding of what happens underneath, so by that time you shouldn't have much problems with this part. What you'll still have to learn are the HTTP protocol (trying to do web programming without understanding the HTTP protocol is like trying to win a car race without knowing how to drive a car - it's not *technically* impossible but it might end up being very painful experience), then front-end stuff (html/css/javascript) and finally the views / templates parts of Django (which should be easy once you know HTTP and html).

You can of course jump right in into Django, but you will probably fight with way too many concepts at once and end up spending twice more time to figure out how everything works and why it works that way.

Comment: As I've said, I am learning Python. The main purpose is to learn how to code. Therefore, mysql concepts are useful in combination with Python & Django. I've learned of the fact that professional developers don't learn sql language specifically. Moreover, they don't consider it  a full fledged programming language.

Comment: I've been a professional developer for 20 years now and I can assure you that "mysql concepts" (actually : "relational databases concepts" - there are quite a few other SQL databases around) are useful by themselves. SQL is not a programming language indeed, but as soon as your code interacts with a SQL database you __do__ have to know how to use this SQL database. Learning to use it "manually" first is faster, let you test / debug your queries without having to touch your application's code at all, and eventually can help you debugging problems with your ORM (if you use one).

Comment: Just to make things clear: SQL is part of the screen testing for developer positions here. If you don't know SQL then you won't be hired. It's as simple as this.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I want to jump right into Django and mysql at the same time. :) My question is whether it is possible without developing a certain application.

Comment: Err... How would you learn to implement a django-based project without doing a project actually ?